# Writing a script to automatically expand disk using all free space with LVM for server workloads

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, disk

I am trying to write a script to programmatically expand a disk (with LVM enabled).

The ubuntu server 22.04 image will be used to create automatically provisioned VM's on a host.

I know of the `sudo lvextend -L +[size] [partition]` command, but I want to automatically query the free space on `/dev/sda` and then pass it to `lvextend`.

In all scenarios, there will only be 1 disk with variable free space, and I want to automatically expand the linux partition to take up all of it.

My `df -h` looks like this:

```
runner@hya-worker-temp:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                               91M  928K   90M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  7.6G  3.9G  3.3G  55% /
tmpfs                              453M     0  453M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          1.7G  126M  1.5G   8% /boot
/dev/sda1                          537M  5.3M  532M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                               91M  4.0K   91M   1% /run/user/1001
```

How can I query the free space and pass it on to `lvextend` from a `.sh` script, or is there an even simpler way to expand the storage.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to automate something so dangerous as partition operations? If so, please include a `dd` backup function into your script.

Comment: @mashuptwice how would I set that up?

Comment: To be honest, I would not. Do you have an option to provision the VMs with the right partition layout right from the beginning? Also: "My fdisk -l looks like this:" but you've added the output of `df -h`

Comment: @mashuptwice well the image is built with a 15 GB disk partition, unless there is a way to automatically take up all the space on the final disk it's my only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following script that does exactly what I need:

```
growpart /dev/sda 3
pvresize /dev/sda3
lvresize -l+100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Answer (score 0):

I think whether your sized disk automatically extend that depends on which allocated storage type you set.

Just use VirtualBox for an example, if you choose `fixed size storage`, that disk size do not automatically expand; if choose `Dynamically allocated storage`, the disk do automatically expand.

But not matter where you set dynamically allocated, in `VirtualBox`, or even `Hy-V`, that disk has the maximum size. E.g: Debian/Ubuntu's max size of dynamical space is `12GB`.

So, when your disk has been used up to `12GB`, you need to manually expand the VM's disk space again.

Recently, I just set my VM Debian to dynamically expand, just like you do, and set the space size of VM up `12GB`, but a few months later, all of my VM Debian's disk space has been used up to `100%`, so I have to spend a week to learn how to manually expand my VM's disk size, because my VM says `Low disk space, only less than 100MB free!`. Oh, my past dear days!

Notice: if the used percent of a disk up to `80`, that is the 80% used disk, that disk is in dangerous status.

In all, I suggest you enable more space to your VM, e.g: `30GB` or even `60GB`.

OVER!

Comment: I am hosting the VM on cloud for server purposes, the disk is set up with LVM, I have put an answer with the script, but thanks for the information